# Changing a loop to Promise.all()

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm currently iterating through an array, making an api request, waiting for it to resolve, then moving onto the next api call.

I've read of using `Promise.all()` and I think I could make these api calls in parallel and wait for that promise to resolve, but I'm not exactly sure how to translate what I have here to use `Promise.all()`.

```
async lockFolder(folderModel) {
        const driveId = folderModel.driveId;

    // THIS IS WHAT I'D LIKE TO TRANSLATE TO USE Promise.all()
    for (const file of folderModel.docs) {
        let res = await this._lockFile(file.id, driveId);
    }

    // return something....
}

async _lockFile(fileId, driveId) {
    try {
        return await axios.post(myRequestOmittedForBrevity);

    } catch (err) {
        //some error
    }

}
```

Is there a good way to translate my loop to `Promise.all()`? Can I still use `await` for it's response? Most examples I've seen use `.then()` but I've been trying to stick with `await`. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

It makes total sense to use Promise.all or Promise.allSettled for this, as soon your requests aren't dependent on each other.
It can be something like this:

```
async lockFolder(folderModel) {
        const driveId = folderModel.driveId;

    // THIS IS WHAT I'D LIKE TO TRANSLATE TO USE Promise.all()
    const listOfPendingPromises = folderModel.docs.map(file => this._lockFile(file.id, driveId))

    const resultArray = await Promise.all(listOfPendingPromises)

    // return something....
}

async _lockFile(fileId, driveId) {  
        return await axios.post(myRequestOmittedForBrevity);
}
```

Comment: `return wait` should be only `return`, or else you are waiting that the promise is resolved.

Comment: yup, that's a valid comment await could be committed there, but there is no or else, the behavior will be exactly the same in both cases. I just left it as it was in example.

Comment: @Denis Malykhin Thanks Denis, that's exactly what I needed in order to understand this better!